# Send email notification when a cell in a column is lower than 50

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'd need your help with Google script to send an email notification.

I need to sent a notification when a value into the column A is lower than 50.

For example: as soon as a cell into the entire column A is lower than 50, and email should be sent mentioning: column A, line 14 reached 49. !Warning!

Do you have any idea of how should I proceed ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this by installing an "on Edit" trigger. The function specified in the trigger would be executed when the spreadsheet is changed. You could then check the cell for your condition and send the email notification using the GMail.App

Does this help?